# How can I know which folders are created by which program?

Tags: package-management, filesystem, directory

I have `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/` and I think it maybe due to `Mousepad` or `Geany` or `Medit` text editors. But how can I know for sure without uninstalling them and reinstalling one-by-one?

(I don't know what tag to use so I put `gtk`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```shell
apt-cache depends <package-name>  |  grep gtksourceview
```

With Mousepad, I get this:

```shell
$ apt-cache depends mousepad | grep gtksourceview
  Depends: libgtksourceview2.0-0
```

The others (Geany and Medit) don't depend on version 2.0 of GtkSourceView.

---

As a side note, to check which packages provide a directory/file, you can use `dpkg -S <package-name>` if the file is in your system or `apt-file` for the general case:

```shell
dpkg -S /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0       # local file/directory
apt-file find /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0 # works even if the file is not installed
```

Since `apt-file` is not installed by default you need to `sudo apt-get install apt-file`. With the above command, I get (among other results) the package `libgtksourceview2.0-common`. Now I can use `apt-cache rdepends` to seek for packages which directly/indirectly provide the directory:

```shell
$ apt-cache rdepends libgtksourceview2.0-common
libgtksourceview2.0-common
Reverse Depends:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-0

$ apt-cache rdepends libgtksourceview2.0-0 | grep 'geany\|medit\|mousepad'
  mousepad
```

This also seems to work (and possibly more general):

```shell
apt-cache rdepends libgtksourceview2.0-common \
  --recurse \
  --no-recommends \
  --no-suggests | grep 'geany\|medit\|mousepad'
```

Comment: While `apt-file` is certainly useful, to find the owner of a file that's _already on your system_ it's probably more efficient to use `dpkg -S <filename>` I think

Comment: @steeldriver Certainly, I'll update the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a search through the packages.ubuntu.com at 'search the contents of a package' level, choosing 'packages that contain files whose names contain the keyword'.
[That will tell us](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gtksourceview-2.0&mode=filename&suite=saucy&arch=any):
a bunch of results in /usr/share/*/gtksourceview-2.0<strike>, but not exactly your folder. So, maybe not what you're looking for...</strike>
*If you search in all (or at least the right) releases, Lucid in this case, it showes up:*
libgtksourceview2.0-common uses that folder...
http ://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/libgtksourceview2.0-common/filelist

Continuing at Google:
searching for the exact foldername, it tells us (with others) to look at www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xfce/gtksourceview2.html.
There it shows us that its one of the original folders for this piece of software (as LFS aims to use original software, where Debian-like distro's allows themselfs to use customized software)

So, you probably build (some piece of software that included) gtksourceview-2.0 as sourcecode. Or some .deb has left the original folder in to exist/be created.

To find out what depends on libgtksourceview2.0-common, you can use `apt-cache rdepends libgtksourceview2.0-common`, which tells us 'libgtksourceview2.0-0'. Check that, it tells us:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libgtksourceview2.0
libgtksourceview2.0-0
Reverse Depends:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0:i386
  x2
  ruby-gtksourceview2
  python-gtksourceview2
  pspp
  oregano
  mousepad
  matita
  marionnet
  liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml
  libgtksourceview2.0-dev
  libgtksourceview2-2.0-cil
  libgtk2-sourceview2-perl
  libgsql0
  leksah
  lekhonee-gnome
  laby
  k3d
  gwyddion
  gummi
  gsql
  gretl
  gobby-0.4
  gnusim8085
  gnome-genius
  gnoemoe
  gmysqlcc
  frama-c
  drivel
  denemo
  cameleon
  bibledit-gtk
  balsa
  alt-ergo
libgtksourceview2.0-dev
Reverse Depends:
  libgtksourceview2.0-dev:i386
  python-gtksourceview2
  liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml-dev
  libghc-gtksourceview2-dev
libgtksourceview2.0-common
Reverse Depends:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-0
libgtksourceview2.0-doc
Reverse Depends:
  libgtksourceview2.0-dev
```

So your feeling of `mousepad` was correct